# Kafka console consumer ERROR "Offset commit failed on partition"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using a `kafka-console-consumer` to probe a kafka topic.

Intermittently, I am getting this error message, followed by 2 warnings:

```
[2018-05-01 18:14:38,888] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-56648] Offset commit failed on partition my-topic-0 at offset 444: The coordinator is not aware of this member. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2018-05-01 18:14:38,888] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-56648] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=444, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

[2018-05-01 18:14:38,888] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-56648] Synchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=447, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
```

It suggested in the warn logs that:

> This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

So, I either need to increase `max.poll.interval.ms` or decrease `max.poll.records`.

Please advise what would be the implication of each method, and which one is preferred on a different situation?

Comment: Can you describe how you fixed your case in detail?

Comment: what's the default value of this two

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you increase `max.poll.interval.ms` that says “it’s ok to spend time processing a large batch of records” and you’ll gain throughput if you can process larger batches more efficiently than smaller ones.

To decrease `max.poll.records` says ”take fewer records so there’s enough time to process them” and would favor latency over throughput.

Also consider that both are configured fine, but something else is causing performance issues within your `poll` loop. I would explore that first before changing configuration so you don’t mask a bigger problem.

Comment: How can we know what is causing a performance issue in the poll loop?

Comment: Check for something obvious like blocking on a network call to a slow service, otherwise go to whatever tools you'd normally use to diagnose performance.